# vb.net ClassNotRegistered error only in Release

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

This is a legacy project in vb.net. When I run it in debug there are no errors but when I create a release version and run it in VS, I get a class not registered error when the code tries to instantiate a form. I am pretty sure the error has to do with a Crystal Reports dll, perhaps AxCrystal, but of course there is no useful information, like, which class.

Any suggestions, hints, anything are very welcome.

Comment: _there is no useful information_. Oh, the irony. ;)

Comment: Maybe `Debug`is being build to x86 and `Release` to x64 or vice versa, and there's a class that's only registered to one of those targets.

Comment: Thank you. That was intelligent. I did look but not the case. Both release and debug are for Any CPU. It's a legacy app but unfortunately also critical. Built by a large team all long gone so that leaves me to figure this out. I'm going to try to deploy the debug build to a user and see if that works. Desperation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register the class as it is described [here](http://www.crystaladvice.com/crystalreports/fix-class-not-registered-crystalprintcontrol):

> A solution for this problem is to register the PrintContoll.dll
>
> First the Crystal Reports 2010 SP1 Redistributable needs to be installed.
>   Then download the following file containing the PrintControll.dll:
>
> ActiveXControls Crystal Reports 2011 SP1
>
> Extract the folder ‘ActiveXControls’ to:
>
> C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\Crystal Reports 2011\crystalreportviewers